# BTG from BTC in BlockChain Wallet

Tags: blockchain.info, bitcoin-gold

Is blockchain wallet able to give us `BTG` once have `BTC` in the wallet on the 25th of October 2017?

I haven't found any confirmation from them and in the btg website there is no info about `blockchain.info` only other wallets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recover your seed phrase from [their website](https://blockchain.info/wallet/#/settings/security) (Settings > Security > Backup Phrase)

You should be able to use this phrase to restore your BTC and BTG in another wallet.